# m2e configuration settings 404 error

Tags: magento, settings, m2e-pro

I just installed M2E and I'm going through the setup process, but when I go to the M2E configurations in the settings->configuration All I am presented with is a 404 error. I have did some looking and I feel like I'm a lonely case. has anyone had this problem or know how to fix it... thank you so much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Log out of your admin, then log back in.